# .htaccess force "www." on everything but subdomains and remove trailing slashes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, this messes up all subdomains doing the following redirect:

```
sub.domain.com -> www.sub.domain.com
```

And also, its dependant on the domain written on the remove trailing slash bit.

So... two questions.

How do I rewrite the rule on the "remove trailing slash" bit to exclude writing the domain on it?

How do I make a rewritecond to exclude subdomains, without explicitly writing them down, on the "force www." bit?

Examples of desired results -

```
sub.domain.com/something/ -> sub.domain.com/something
domain.com/something/ -> www.domain.com/something
www.domain.com/ -> www.domain.com
sub.domain.com -> sub.domain.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you want to have happen.  Can you provide a set of inputs and what you want them transformed into?

Comment: I added some examples!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the www to check for the actual domain:

```
#Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or, if you're hosting a bunch of domains, you can check for a name before the TLD:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As for the trailing slash, you have to be careful that the request isn't made for a directory. Because if it is, and you have `DirectorySlash` turned on (by default it is on), then you'll cause a redirect loop.

To exclude subdomains, we assume that the first rule redirected the browser to ensure that it started with "www", and since subdomains aren't being redirected to start with "www", we can just check for that:

```
#Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I used the second option for `force www`. Both that one and the `remove trailing slash` bit worked perfectly.
Would you mind explaining the regexp and the logic in the `force www` one?

Comment: @OhCaN We want a single `.` in the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable, so `^` is the beginning of the string, then `([^.]+)` is one or more characters that isn't a `.`, then a `.`, then `([a-z]{2,4})` matches between 2 to 4 characters that are letters (a-z), and `$` is the end of the string.