# .htaccess force 'www.' and append the rest of url to the end as normal

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

Right, I have a .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foto/([\w-]+).jpg fotos.php?pic1=$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^afbeeldingen/([\w-]+).jpg fotos.php?pic=$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^header/([\w-]+).jpg header.php?head_jpg=$1 [L,NS] 
RewriteRule ^header/([\w-]+).png header.php?head_png=$1 [L,NS] 
RewriteRule ^def/([\w-]+).jpg def_header.php?head_def=$1 [L,NS] 

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php 
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

The question concerns only the last 2 lines, namely I want to force 'www.' in front of all urls. This is the result that I want when trying to access the sitemap.xml:

```
http://domain.com/sitemap.xml -> http://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
http://domain.com/sitemap.xml -> http://www.domain.com/index.php
```

All other url's seem to be working fine (thanks to anubhava). The 'www.' is forced properly on url's such as http://domain.com/category/article -> http://www.domain.com/category/article

After reading the following stack question ([.htaccess force "www." on everything but subdomains and remove trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167508/htaccess-force-www-on-everything-but-subdomains-and-remove-trailing-slashes)) I have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

without any succes. I have also tried changing the order in which the rules are put (i.e. the rewrite condition and rule underneath `RewriteEngine On`) which doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm using the Yii Framework.

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

I forgot to mention that I do NOT actually have a sitemap.xml file in the root, rather I am using Yii's urlManager to reroute to a controller action to generate the sitemap.xml like so:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    // 'matchValue' => true,
    'rules'=>array( 
        ...
        'sitemap.xml'=>'site/sitemapxml',
        ...
    ),
),
```

The urlManager generates a .htaccess file itself, which is most likely buggering with my own .htaccess file. Any idea's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of rules matter in .htaccess.

Move this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Thanks for answering mate, your answer solved my problem concerning the url: http://domain.com/category/article (it forces the www. nicely). It however does not solve the problem for the url: http://domain.com/sitemap.xml -> www.domain.com/index.php
- I am still getting the same result

Comment: I don't know much of `Yii` but can you try `domain.com/site/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: Sorry good sir, it seemed I had either made a mistake modifying my .htaccess or made some other clumsy mistake somewhere else. After trying your answer again, I seem to be getting the correct results, with all url's including domain.com/sitemap.xml -> www.domain.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Same as the answer from anubhava - this also does not solve my problem with the url:
domain.com/sitemap.xml -> www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: Are you sure the file sitemap.xml exists?

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you try this (reordered)?

Comment: After updating the .htaccess to this, the www. isn't forced anywhere anymore. However, because of your question "are you sure the file sitemap.xml exists?" I realized that I don't actually have a sitemap.xml file in the root, rather I am using Yii's urlmanager to reroute to a controller action to generate the sitemap.xml when the url "domain.com/sitemap.xml" is called. This most likely effects what we're trying to do with our .htaccess. I will update my question with this :)

Comment: Yes, it's likely because of that. I've restored my initial answer.